# node.js - Can't figure out how to sabe sessions with session-express

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, express-session

I'm new to node.js and sessions, I'm trying to store some values in the node.js session, but everytime I reload the page and check the console.log the session haven't been saved. My code:

```
var session;
var org;

function checkSession(argument){
  var sess = argument;
  if(sess.org){
    return null;
  }
  else{
    return sess.org;
  }
}
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  session = req.session;
  var sessionChecked = checkSession(session);
  if(sessionChecked){
    org = sessionChecked;
  }
  else{
    org = req.query.org || 'Google';
    session.org = org;
    session.save();
  }
```

So basically what I want is, when the user loads the page for the first time, he can type a organization, and when he does that, this organization is saved on the session, so when he reloads the page, the organization is already selected.

I know I must be doing something really wrong and/or bad codding, but I just can't figure this out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that my session was expiring in 20 seconds. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like calling `session.save()` isn't doing what you expect. Express won't write to the session unless the route is fully processed. You likely need to call `res.end()` at the end of your get function.

Take a look at https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsession and try to understand each line of code in that example.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it seems that I can't do that because I'm already rendering the body, so I get this error "Can't set headers after they are sent". This demo code seems to be using the same logic as mine, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I don't see that from the code example you posted. Perhaps try to remove the call to `save()` altogether as Express will automatically save the session data *if* the route is completed. It also might be possible that you are returning the body before you set the session information, but I don't see that in your code.

Comment: Thank you!

So this is my index.js: http://pastebin.com/uqSKV1Ms

And this is my app.js: http://pastebin.com/bhqTm96L